# How to add information siding an image on a tex file powered by moderncv.cls file?

Tags: moderncv

I try to modify a resume template named `moderncv.cls` to add some information siding the picture on the right. Indeed, I want to add my age and my driver license type for instance. I am using overleaf and it uses an outdated version 2012/10/31 v1.2.0 of moderncv.

[image: Screenshot of the profile]

Yet, adding some information on the `.tex` file and on the `.cls` file, it didn't changed anything.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\selectlanguage{french}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{14.7cm}    

\firstname{Antoine} % Your first name
\familyname{Friend} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{CV Bidon}
\email{antoine.compagnie@gmail.com}
\address{somewhere}{Paris, 75000}
\mobile{(+33) 0000000}
\age{24 ans}
\license{Permis B}
\familly{célibataire et sans enfant}

\section{Formation}


\cventry{2017--2018}{Master 2 Informatique des Organisations Parcours Informatique : Systèmes Intelligents }{Université Paris-Dauphine et AgroParisTech}{}{}{} 

\end{document}
\enddocument
```

Here follows the whole `.cls` file. I added few commands such as :

```
\newcommand*{\age}[1]{\def\@age{#1}}
\newcommand*{\license}[1]{\def\@license{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familly}[1]{\def\@familly{#1}}
```

But it doesn't appear.

```
%% start of file `moderncv.cls'.
%% Copyright 2006-2012 Xavier Danaux (xdanaux@gmail.com).
%
% This work may be distributed and/or modified under the
% conditions of the LaTeX Project Public License version 1.3c,
% available at http://www.latex-project.org/lppl/.


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                identification
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{moderncv}[2012/10/31 v1.2.0 modern curriculum vitae and letter document class]


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                class options
%
% (need to be done before the external package loading, for example because
% we need \paperwidth, \paperheight and \@ptsize to be defined before loading
% geometry and fancyhdr)
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% paper size option
\DeclareOption{a4paper}{
  \setlength\paperheight{297mm}
  \setlength\paperwidth{210mm}}
\DeclareOption{a5paper}{
  \setlength\paperheight{210mm}
  \setlength\paperwidth{148mm}}
\DeclareOption{b5paper}{
  \setlength\paperheight{250mm}
  \setlength\paperwidth{176mm}}
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}{
  \setlength\paperheight{11in}
  \setlength\paperwidth{8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{legalpaper}{
  \setlength\paperheight{14in}
  \setlength\paperwidth{8.5in}}
\DeclareOption{executivepaper}{
  \setlength\paperheight{10.5in}
  \setlength\paperwidth{7.25in}}
\DeclareOption{landscape}{
  \setlength\@tempdima{\paperheight}
  \setlength\paperheight{\paperwidth}
  \setlength\paperwidth{\@tempdima}}

% font size options
\newcommand\@ptsize{}
\DeclareOption{10pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{0}}
\DeclareOption{11pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{1}}
\DeclareOption{12pt}{\renewcommand\@ptsize{2}}

% font type options
\DeclareOption{sans}{\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}}}
\DeclareOption{roman}{\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}}}

% draft/final option
\DeclareOption{draft}{\setlength\overfullrule{5pt}}
\DeclareOption{final}{\setlength\overfullrule{0pt}}

% execute default options
\ExecuteOptions{a4paper,11pt,final}

% process given options
\ProcessOptions\relax
\input{size1\@ptsize.clo}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                required packages
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% \AtEndPreamble hook (loading etoolbox instead of defining the macro, as to avoid incompatibilities with etoolbox (and packages relying on it) defining the macro too)
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}
%\let\@endpreamblehook\@empty
%\def\AtEndPreamble{\g@addto@macro\@endpreamblehook}
%\let\document@original\document
%\def\document{\endgroup\@endpreamblehook\begingroup\document@original}

% if... then... else... constructs
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
% TODO: move to xifthen and \isempty{<arg>} instead of \equal{<arg>}{}

% color
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

% font loading
%\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}
%\newif\ifxetexorluatex
%\ifxetex
%  \xetexorluatextrue
%\else
%  \ifluatex
%    \xetexorluatextrue
%  \else
%    \xetexorluatexfalse
%  \fi
%\fi
% automatic loading of latin modern fonts
%\ifxetexorluatex
%  \RequirePackage{fontspec}
%  \defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
%  \RequirePackage{unicode-math}
%  \setmainfont{Latin Modern}
%  \setsansfont{Latin Modern Sans}
%  \setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
%\else
  \RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \IfFileExists{lmodern.sty}%
    {\RequirePackage{lmodern}}%
    {}
%\fi

% MarVoSym font for symbols
%\RequirePackage{marvosym}
\newcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{}
%\ifxetexorluatex
%  \renewcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{{\fontspec{MarVoSym}\char#1}}
%\else
  \renewcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{{\fontfamily{mvs}\fontencoding{U}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\char#1}}
%\fi

% hyper links (hyperref is loaded at the end of the preamble to pass options required by loaded packages such as CJK)
\RequirePackage{url}
\urlstyle{tt}
\AtEndPreamble{
  \pagenumbering{arabic}% has to be issued before loading hyperref, as to set \thepage and hence to avoid hyperref issuing a warning and setting pdfpagelabels=false
  \RequirePackage[unicode]{hyperref}% unicode is required for unicode pdf metadata
  \hypersetup{
    breaklinks,
    baseurl       = http://,
    pdfborder     = 0 0 0,
    pdfpagemode   = UseNone,% do not show thumbnails or bookmarks on opening
    pdfstartpage  = 1,
    pdfcreator    = {\LaTeX{} with 'moderncv' package},
%    pdfproducer   = {\LaTeX{}},% will/should be set automatically to the correct TeX engine used
    bookmarksopen = true,
    bookmarksdepth= 2,% to show sections and subsections
    pdfauthor     = {\@firstname{}~\@familyname{}},
    pdftitle      = {\@firstname{}~\@familyname{} -- \@title{}},
    pdfsubject    = {Resum\'{e} of \@firstname{}~\@familyname{}},
    pdfkeywords   = {\@firstname{}~\@familyname{}, curriculum vit\ae{}, resum\'{e}}}}

% graphics
\RequirePackage{graphicx}

% headers and footers
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}}
% page numbers in footer if more than 1 page
\newif\if@displaypagenumbers\@displaypagenumberstrue
\newcommand*{\nopagenumbers}{\@displaypagenumbersfalse}
\AtEndPreamble{%
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \if@displaypagenumbers%
      \@ifundefined{r@lastpage}{}{%
        \ifthenelse{\pageref{lastpage}>1}{%
          \newlength{\pagenumberwidth}%
          \settowidth{\pagenumberwidth}{\color{color2}\addressfont\itshape\strut\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}}%
          \fancypagestyle{plain}{%
            \fancyfoot[r]{\parbox[b]{\pagenumberwidth}{\color{color2}\addressfont\itshape\strut\thepage/\pageref{lastpage}}}}% the parbox is required to ensure alignment with a possible center footer (e.g., as in the casual style)
          \pagestyle{plain}}{}}%
      \AtEndDocument{\label{lastpage}}\else\fi}}
\pagestyle{plain}

% lengths calculations
\RequirePackage{calc}

% advanced command arguments (LaTeX 3)
\RequirePackage{xargs}
% TODO (?): replace all \newcommand by \NewDocumentCommand

% micro-typography (e.g., character protrusion, font expansion, hyphenatable letterspacing)
\RequirePackage{microtype}

% compatibility package with older versions of moderncv
\RequirePackageWithOptions{moderncvcompatibility}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                class definition
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% minimal base settings
\setlength\lineskip{1\p@}
\setlength\normallineskip{1\p@}
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{}
\setlength{\parindent}{0\p@}
\setlength{\parskip}{0\p@}
\setlength\columnsep{10\p@}
\setlength\columnseprule{0\p@}
\setlength\fboxsep{3\p@}
\setlength\fboxrule{.4\p@}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.4\p@}
\setlength\doublerulesep{2\p@}

% not set on purpose
%\setlength\arraycolsep{5\p@}
%\setlength\tabcolsep{6\p@}
%\setlength\tabbingsep{\labelsep}

\raggedbottom
\onecolumn


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                overall design commands definitions
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% elements
\newcommand*{\firstname}[1]{\def\@firstname{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familyname}[1]{\def\@familyname{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\title}[1]{\def\@title{#1}}
\newcommand*{\age}[1]{\def\@age{#1}}
\newcommand*{\license}[1]{\def\@license{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familly}[1]{\def\@familly{#1}}
\newcommand*{\address}[2]{\def\@addressstreet{#1}\def\@addresscity{#2}}
\newcommand*{\mobile}[1]{\def\@mobile{#1}}
\newcommand*{\phone}[1]{\def\@phone{#1}}
\newcommand*{\fax}[1]{\def\@fax{#1}}
\newcommand*{\email}[1]{\def\@email{#1}}
\newcommand*{\homepage}[2]{\def\@homepage{#1}\def\@homepagetitle{#2}}

% colors
\definecolor{color0}{rgb}{0,0,0}% main default color, normally left to black
\definecolor{color1}{rgb}{0,0,0}% primary theme color
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0,0,0}% secondary theme color
\definecolor{color3}{rgb}{0,0,0}% tertiary theme color

% symbols
%   itemize labels (the struts were added to correct inter-item spacing (works for single line items, until a solution is found for multi-line ones...)
\newcommand*{\labelitemi}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\marvosymbol{123}}}% equivalent to \Neutral from marvosym package; alternative: \fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{ding}\selectfont\tiny\symbol{'102}
\newcommand*{\labelitemii}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\large\bfseries-}}
\newcommand*{\labelitemiii}{\strut\textcolor{color1}{\rmfamily\textperiodcentered}}% alternative: \textasteriskcentered; the \rmfamily is required to force Latin Modern fonts when using sans serif, as OMS/lmss/m/n is not defined and gets substituted by OMS/cmsy/m/n
\newcommand*{\labelitemiv}{\labelitemiii}
%   enumerate labels
\renewcommand{\theenumi}{\@arabic\c@enumi}
\renewcommand{\theenumii}{\@alph\c@enumii}
\renewcommand{\theenumiii}{\@roman\c@enumiii}
\renewcommand{\theenumiv}{\@Alph\c@enumiv}
%   other symbols
\newcommand*{\listitemsymbol}{\labelitemi~}
\newcommand*{\agesymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\licensesymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\famillysymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\addresssymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\mobilesymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\phonesymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\faxsymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\emailsymbol}{}
\newcommand*{\homepagesymbol}{}

% fonts
\AtBeginDocument{\normalfont\color{color0}}

% strings for internationalisation
\newcommand*{\refname}{Publications}
\newcommand*{\enclname}{Enclosure}

% makes the footer (normally used both for the resume and the letter)
% usage: \makefooter
\newcommand*{\makefooter}{}%

% loads a style scheme
\newcommand*{\moderncvstyle}[1]{
  \RequirePackage{moderncvstyle#1}}

% loads a color scheme
\newcommand*{\moderncvcolor}[1]{
  \RequirePackage{moderncvcolor#1}}

% recomputes all automatic lengths
\newcommand*{\recomputelengths}{\recomputecvlengths}
\AtBeginDocument{\recomputelengths{}}

% creates a length if not yet defined
\newcommand*{\@initializelength}[1]{%
  \ifdefined#1\else\newlength{#1}\fi}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                resume design commands definitions
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% elements
\newcommand*{\extrainfo}[1]{\def\@extrainfo{#1}}
\newcommandx*{\photo}[3][1=64pt,2=0.4pt,usedefault]{\def\@photowidth{#1}\def\@photoframewidth{#2}\def\@photo{#3}}% the 1st (optional) argument is the width of the photo, the 2nd (optional) argument is the thickness of the frame around it.
\newcommand*{\quote}[1]{\def\@quote{#1}}

% fonts
\newcommand*{\namefont}{}
\newcommand*{\titlefont}{}
\newcommand*{\addressfont}{}
\newcommand*{\quotefont}{}
\newcommand*{\sectionfont}{}
\newcommand*{\subsectionfont}{}
\newcommand*{\hintfont}{}

% styles
\newcommand*{\namestyle}[1]{{\namefont#1}}
\newcommand*{\titlestyle}[1]{{\titlefont#1}}
\newcommand*{\addressstyle}[1]{{\addressfont#1}}
\newcommand*{\quotestyle}[1]{{\quotefont#1}}
\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}[1]{{\sectionfont#1}}
\newcommand*{\subsectionstyle}[1]{{\subsectionfont#1}}
\newcommand*{\hintstyle}[1]{{\hintfont#1}}

% recompute all resume lengths
\newcommand*{\recomputecvlengths}{}

% internal maketitle command to issue a new line only when required
\newif\if@firstdetailselement\@firstdetailselementtrue
\newcommand*{\makenewline}{
  \if@firstdetailselement%
    \strut% to ensure baseline alignment, e.g. with when put in the margin vs sections that also contains a \strut
  \else%
    \\\fi%
  \@firstdetailselementfalse}

% makes the resume title
% usage: \makecvtitle
\newcommand*{\makecvtitle}{}

% makes the resume footer
% usage: \makecvfooter
\newcommand*{\makecvfooter}{\makefooter}

% makes a resume section
% usage: \section{<title>}
\newcommand*{\section}[1]{}
% starred variant, which is identical but defined to allow its use (e.g. for natbib compatibility, who uses \section*{} for the bibliography header)
\RequirePackage{suffix}
\AtBeginDocument{\WithSuffix\newcommand\section*{\section}}

% makes a resume subsection
% usage: \subsection{title}
\newcommand*{\subsection}[1]{}
\AtBeginDocument{\WithSuffix\newcommand\subsection*{\subsection}}

% makes a resume line with a header and a corresponding text
% usage: \cvitem[spacing]{header}{text}
\newcommand*{\cvitem}[3][.25em]{}

% makes a resume line 2 headers and their corresponding text
% usage: \cvdoubleitem[spacing]{header1}{text1}{header2}{text2}
\newcommand*{\cvdoubleitem}[5][.25em]{}

% makes a resume line with a list item
% usage: \cvlistitem[label]{item}
\newcommand*{\cvlistitem}[2][\listitemsymbol]{}

% makes a resume line with 2 list items
% usage: \cvlistdoubleitem[label]{item1}{item2}
\newcommand*{\cvlistdoubleitem}[3][\listitemsymbol]{}

% makes a typical resume job / education entry
% usage: \cventry[spacing]{years}{degree/job title}{institution/employer}{localization}{optionnal: grade/...}{optional: comment/job description}
\newcommand*{\cventry}[7][.25em]{}

% makes a resume entry with a proficiency comment
% usage: \cvitemwithcomment[spacing]{header}{text}{comment}
\newcommand*{\cvitemwithcomment}[4][.25em]{}

% makes a generic hyperlink
% usage: \link[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\link}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{#2}{#1}}}

% makes a http hyperlink
% usage: \httplink[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\httplink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{http://#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{http://#2}{#1}}}

% makes an email hyperlink
% usage: \emaillink[optional text]{link}
\newcommand*{\emaillink}[2][]{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
    {\href{mailto:#2}{#2}}%
    {\href{mailto:#2}{#1}}}

% thebibliography environment, for use with BibTeX and possibly multibib
\newlength{\bibindent}
\setlength{\bibindent}{1.5em}
% bibliography item label
\newcommand*{\bibliographyitemlabel}{}% use \@biblabel{\arabic{enumiv}} for BibTeX labels
%\newif\if@multibibfirstbib\@multibibfirstbibfalse
% bibliography head (section, etc}, depending on whether multibib is used
\newcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{\section{#1}}
\AtEndPreamble{\@ifpackageloaded{multibib}{\renewcommand*{\bibliographyhead}[1]{\subsection{#1}}}{}}
% thebibliography environment definition
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]{}{}
\newcommand*{\newblock}{\hskip .11em\@plus.33em\@minus.07em}
\let\@openbib@code\@empty

% itemize, enumerate and description environment
\setlength{\leftmargini}   {1em}
\leftmargin\leftmargini
\setlength{\leftmarginii}  {\leftmargini}
\setlength{\leftmarginiii} {\leftmargini}
\setlength{\leftmarginiv}  {\leftmargini}
\setlength{\leftmarginv}   {\leftmargini}
\setlength{\leftmarginvi}  {\leftmargini}
\setlength{\labelsep}      {.5em}% this is the distance between the label and the body, but it pushes the label to the left rather than pushing the body to the right (to do the latter, modify \leftmargin(i)
\setlength{\labelwidth}    {\leftmargini}% unfortunately, \labelwidth is not defined by item level (i.e. no \labeliwidth, \labeliiwidth, etc)
\addtolength{\labelwidth}  {-\labelsep}
\@beginparpenalty -\@lowpenalty
\@endparpenalty   -\@lowpenalty
\@itempenalty     -\@lowpenalty
\newcommand\labelenumi{\theenumi.}
\newcommand\labelenumii{(\theenumii)}
\newcommand\labelenumiii{\theenumiii.}
\newcommand\labelenumiv{\theenumiv.}
\renewcommand\p@enumii{\theenumi}
\renewcommand\p@enumiii{\p@enumii(\theenumii)}
\renewcommand\p@enumiv{\p@enumiii\theenumiii}
% description label
\newcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont\bfseries#1}
% hooks to adjust spacing (idea by Jakob Schiøtz; see http://dcwww.camd.dtu.dk/~schiotz/comp/LatexTips/tweaklist.sty)
\RequirePackage{tweaklist}% distributed with moderncv, not found on ctan and slightly modified
\renewcommand*{\itemhook}{
  \setlength{\topsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parsep}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}}
\renewcommand*{\enumhook}{\itemhook{}}
\renewcommand*{\deschook}{\itemhook{}}

% classical \today definition
\def\today{\ifcase\month\or
  January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
  July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi
  \space\number\day, \number\year}

%\newcommand{\widthofautobox}[1]{%
%  \widthof{\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}

%\newcommand{\autobox}[2][b]{%
%  \parbox[#1]{\widthofautobox{#2}}{#2}}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%                letter design commands definitions
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% elements
\newcommand*{\recipient}[2]{\def\@recipientname{#1}\def\@recipientaddress{#2}}
\renewcommand*{\date}[1]{\def\@date{#1}}\date{\today}
\newcommand*{\opening}[1]{\def\@opening{#1}}
\newcommand*{\closing}[1]{\def\@closing{#1}}
\newcommand*{\enclosure}[2][]{%
  % if an optional argument is provided, use it to redefine \enclname
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{}{\renewcommand*{\enclname}{#1}}%
  \def\@enclosure{#2}}

% recompute all letter lengths
\newcommand*{\recomputeletterlengths}{}

% makes the letter title
% usage: \makelettertitle
\newcommand*{\makelettertitle}{}

% makes the letter footer
% usage: \makeletterfooter
\newcommand*{\makeletterfooter}{\makefooter}

% makes the letter closing
% usage: \makeletterclosing
\newcommand*{\makeletterclosing}{}


\endinput


%% end of file `moderncv.cls'.
```

A read only link is available [here](https://www.overleaf.com/read/tvjdnxjhvwxw) on overleaf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see that overleaf uses an outdated version `2012/10/31 v1.2.0` of moderncv.

You can patch the unchanged original version 1.2 of class `moderncv` with the following commands:

```
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{%search
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
        }{%replace
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@license}}{}{\makenewline\@license}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@familly}}{}{\makenewline\@familly}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@age}}{}{\makenewline\@age}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
        }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
```

Because this code uses the `@` you have to enclose it with `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.  Just see the following complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\selectlanguage{french}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\setlength{\makecvtitlenamewidth}{14.7cm}    

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\age}[1]{\def\@age{#1}}
\newcommand*{\license}[1]{\def\@license{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familly}[1]{\def\@familly{#1}}

\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{%search
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
        }{%replace
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@license}}{}{\makenewline\@license}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@familly}}{}{\makenewline\@familly}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@age}}{}{\makenewline\@age}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
        }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother

\firstname{Antoine} % Your first name
\familyname{Friend} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{CV Bidon}
\email{antoine.compagnie@gmail.com}
\address{somewhere}{Paris, 75000}
\mobile{(+33) 0000000}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\age{24 ans}
\license{Permis B}
\familly{célibataire et sans enfant}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Formation}


\cventry{2017--2018}{Master 2 Informatique des Organisations Parcours Informatique : Systèmes Intelligents }{Université Paris-Dauphine et AgroParisTech}{}{}{} 

\end{document}
```

with the result:

[image: resulting pdf]

Please see that this version does only work with the old version 1.2! Your code has only to be updated with the code between `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` in the preamble.

If you want to change your used version of `moderncv` to the current one 2.0.0 you have to change the added `\patchcmd` too!

To patch version 2.0.0 you need to change the code I marked with `<=====`. The reason is that simply the names of that variables has been changed (See the examples of version 2.0.0. For example the phone number has a new name too.  Just compare your code with the `template.tex` of `moderncv`):

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} % head 1
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\selectlanguage{french}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 
\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{14.7cm} % <============================

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\age}[1]{\def\@age{#1}}
\newcommand*{\license}[1]{\def\@license{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familly}[1]{\def\@familly{#1}}

\patchcmd{\makecvhead}{%search % <======================================
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
        }{%replace
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@license}}{}{\makenewline\@license}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@familly}}{}{\makenewline\@familly}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@age}}{}{\makenewline\@age}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}%
        }{%success
  }{%failure
  }
\makeatother

\firstname{Antoine} % Your first name
\familyname{Friend} % Your last name

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{CV Bidon}
\email{antoine.compagnie@gmail.com}
\address{somewhere}{Paris, 75000}
\mobile{(+33) 0000000}
\photo[64pt][0.4pt]{example-image-a}
\age{24 ans}
\license{Permis B}
\familly{célibataire et sans enfant}

\begin{document}
\makecvtitle

\section{Formation}


\cventry{2017--2018}{Master 2 Informatique des Organisations Parcours Informatique : Systèmes Intelligents }{Université Paris-Dauphine et AgroParisTech}{}{}{} 

\end{document}
```

and gives the same result.

Answer (score 1):

To add additional information to a `moderncv` document with `classic` style, you could use something like the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv} % Font sizes: 10, 11, or 12; paper sizes: a4paper, letterpaper, a5paper, legalpaper, executivepaper or landscape; font families: sans or roman

\moderncvstyle{classic} 
\moderncvcolor{blue} 

\usepackage[french]{babel}
\selectlanguage{french}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}    

\usepackage[top=1cm,bottom=2cm,right=2cm,left=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{3cm} 

\firstname{Antoine} % Your first name
\familyname{Friend} % Your last name


\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\age}[1]{\def\@age{#1}}
\newcommand*{\license}[1]{\def\@license{#1}}
\newcommand*{\familly}[1]{\def\@familly{#1}}

\renewcommand*{\makecvhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputecvlengths%
  % optional detailed information (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}%
  \if@details%
    \def\phonesdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
      \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \def\socialsdetails{}%
    \collectionloop{socials}{% the key holds the social type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the link
      \protected@edef\socialsdetails{\socialsdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey socialsymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
    \savebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}{%
      \addressfont\color{color2}%
      \if@left\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}r@{}}\fi%
      \if@right\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}\fi%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \phonesdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \socialsdetails% needs to be pre-rendered as loops and tabulars seem to conflict
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@license}}{}{\makenewline\@license}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@familly}}{}{\makenewline\@familly}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@age}}{}{\makenewline\@age}%
      \end{tabular}
    }\fi%
  % optional photo (pre-rendering)
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}{%
    \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@photo}}%
      {}%
      {%
        \if@left%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi%
        \color{color1}%
        \setlength{\fboxrule}{\@photoframewidth}%
        \ifdim\@photoframewidth=0pt%
          \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}\fi%
        \framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}}%
        \if@right%
          \hspace*{\separatorcolumnwidth}\fi}%
  % name and title (pre-rendering)
  \@initializelength{\makecvheaddetailswidth}\settowidth{\makecvheaddetailswidth}{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}%
  \@initializelength{\makecvheadpicturewidth}\settowidth{\makecvheadpicturewidth}{\usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}}%
  \ifthenelse{\lengthtest{\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt}}% check for dummy value (equivalent to \ifdim\makecvheadnamewidth=0pt)
    {\setlength{\makecvheadnamewidth}{\textwidth-\makecvheaddetailswidth-\makecvheadpicturewidth}}%
    {}%
  \@initializebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
  \savebox{\makecvheadnamebox}{%
    \begin{minipage}[b]{\makecvheadnamewidth}%
      \if@left\raggedright\fi%
      \if@right\raggedleft\fi%
      \namestyle{\@firstname\ \@lastname}%
      \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{\\[1.25em]\titlestyle{\@title}}%
    \end{minipage}}%
  % rendering
  \if@left%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}%
    \hfill%
    \llap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}\fi%
  \if@right%
    \usebox{\makecvheadpicturebox}%
    \rlap{\usebox{\makecvheaddetailsbox}}% \llap is used to suppress the width of the box, allowing overlap if the value of makecvheadnamewidth is forced
    \hfill%
    \usebox{\makecvheadnamebox}\fi%
  \\[2.5em]%
  % optional quote
  \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@quote}}%
    {}%
    {{\centering\begin{minipage}{\quotewidth}\centering\quotestyle{\@quote}\end{minipage}\\[2.5em]}}%
  \par}% to avoid weird spacing bug at the first section if no blank line is left after \makecvhead
\makeatother

% All information in this block is optional, comment out any lines you don't need
\title{CV Bidon}
\email{antoine.compagnie@gmail.com}
\address{somewhere}{Paris, 75000}
\mobile{(+33) 0000000}
\age{24 ans}
\license{Permis B}
\familly{célibataire et sans enfant}
\photo[64pt]{example-image}
\begin{document}

\makecvhead
\section{Formation}


\cventry{2017--2018}{Master 2 Informatique des Organisations Parcours Informatique : Systèmes Intelligents }{Université Paris-Dauphine et AgroParisTech}{}{}{} 

\end{document}
```

This MWE works with an unchanged version of the `.cls` file, as I have included the relevant changes into the `.tex` file. (Please keep in mind, that editing an original `.cls` file directly isn't a good idea.)
In order to include the additional information, I have used the commands definitions for `\age`, `\license` and `\familly`. 
As you have observed, only defining them does not leed to the information being printed in the header. 
The `classic` style loads `moderncvheadi.sty` that contains the information on how to arrange the name, address, photo,... I have therefore copied this information and added  the following lines:

```
 \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@license}}{}{\makenewline\@license}%
 \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@familly}}{}{\makenewline\@familly}%
 \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@age}}{}{\makenewline\@age}%
```

These modifications have to take place in the preamble of the `.tex` file between the commands `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother`.

With the above MWE you get the following output:

[image]

Comment: Understood, therefors I should undo the few things I added on the `.cls` and add the code from `\makeatletter` to  `\makeatother` ?

Comment: I tried to undo the few things I added on the .cls file and add the code but it answered me `LaTeX Error: \makecvhead undefined.`

Comment: The modified `.cls` file you posted in your question shows that you are using a quite old version `1.2.0` (2012/10/31) of `moderncv`, while the current one is version  `2.0.0` (2015-07-28). Please see if you can update to the most recent version as my answer is based on version `2.0.0`.

Comment: Fine. I downloaded it from [ctan.org](https://ctan.org/pkg/moderncv). I tried to copy and paste it instead of the old one and the new one wasn't able to recompile with this error : `./moderncvstyleclassic.sty:41: LaTeX Error: \mobilesymbol undefined.`